# Android MediaPlayer - как правильно создать OnErrorListener?

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Как правильно реализовать в Android MediaPlayer OnErrorListener?
Как вызывать функцию setOnErrorListener, с какими параметрами,
как объявлять реализацию обработчика ошибок, onError?
Нужен 100%-но работающий стандартный код.

Вот некоторая заготовка, но тут два раза используется onError. Непонятно, где он должен определяться, внутри onErrorListener или отдельно. И как передавать параметр обработчика в .setOnErrorListener.

```
    public class PlayerService extends Service implements OnErrorListener {
....
////////////////////

this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(url));
mplayer.setOnErrorListener(onErrorListener);
////////////////////

MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onErrorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()   
    {  
         @Override  
         public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)   
         {  
              Log.e(getPackageName(), String.format("Error(%s%s)", what, extra));
              playlist="ERROR";

              restart();
              return true;  
         }  
    };

@Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer player, int what, int extra) {
        restart();
        return true;
    };

public void restart()
    {
        try
        {
        playlist="RELOADING";
        for (int u=1; u<=5; u++)
        {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        mplayer.stop();
        mplayer.release();
        mplayer=null;
    playSong(getApplicationContext(),currenturl);
        };

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        playlist="RELOADING ERROR";

        }

    }
//////////////
....

}
```

Comment: А что Вы сделали самостоятельно и что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: UPDATE, посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

сейчас будет обрабатываться

```
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onErrorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()   
    {  
         @Override  
         public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)   
         {  
              Log.e(getPackageName(), String.format("Error(%s%s)", what, extra));
              playlist="ERROR";

              restart();
              return true;  
         }  
    };
```

потому что он зарегистрирован `mplayer.setOnErrorListener(onErrorListener);`,

что бы зарегистрировать другой, надо `mplayer.setOnErrorListener(this);`

Comment: Если оставляю этот, то пишет the type PlayerService must implement the inherited abstract method MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.onError(MediaPlayer, int, int).
Что не так?

Comment: Если сделать то, что предлагает IDE, то добавляется в конце класса (а не внутрь обработчика) 
@Override
 public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

Comment: послушайся IDE, перенеси нужный код во внутренний класс

Comment: Пробую mplayer.setOnErrorListener(this); , создав функцию onError в классе сервиса. На потерю Сети не реагирует этот обработчик.
Стандартное решение - пример кода - какое?